# How to optimize Mysql Select Query with Union?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, optimization

i am working on mysql database with InnoDb storage engine. 
my table structure are as follows:

Table Name : archiveincomingsms

[image]

Index Detail of : archiveincomingsms

[image]

Table Name : archiveoutgoingsms
[image]

Index Detail of : archiveoutgoingsms
[image]

Above are my table structure and their index detail !

Both table have minimum more then 1 billion records(rows) respectively.

Now Problem is that when i would like to execute following SqlQuery :

```
      ( SELECT  id AS ID, `recieved_datetime` `Date`, 'MT' AS Type, src_adress AS Msisdn,
               TEXT as text, CHAR_LENGTH(TEXT) AS QtyOfSymbols, 'OK' AS `Status`
            FROM  archiveincomingsms
            WHERE  1=1
              AND  recieved_datetime BETWEEN '2015-06-14 00:00:00'
                                         AND '2015-07-14 23:59:59'
      )
    UNION  ALL
      ( SELECT  id AS ID, `send_date` `Date`, 'MO' AS Type, scr_adress AS Msisdn,
                TEXT as text, CHAR_LENGTH(TEXT) AS QtyOfSymbols, 'OK' AS `Status`
            FROM  archiveoutgoingsms
            WHERE  1=1
              AND  send_date BETWEEN '2015-06-14 00:00:00'
                                 AND '2015-07-14 23:59:59'
      )
    ORDER BY  `Date` ASC
    LIMIT  0 ,100
```

Above query takes more than 30 second time to get data from tables.
and Another one is i have to  count number of row too  for pagination purpose and it also take more then 30 second time.

Overall it takes more than 1 minute to execute.
Is there any proper way to optimize time ? 
i have to take down into maximum 5 sec. ! How can it possible ? 
I am using mysql database !

Answer (score 0):

I cann't see indexes.

Please, result of query:

```
EXPLAIN (SELECT id AS ID,`recieved_datetime` `Date`,'MT' AS Type,src_adress AS Msisdn,TEXT as text,CHAR_LENGTH(TEXT) AS QtyOfSymbols,'OK' AS `Status` FROM archiveincomingsms
                  WHERE 1=1 AND recieved_datetime BETWEEN '2015-06-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-14 23:59:59')
                  UNION ALL
                  (SELECT id AS ID,`send_date` `Date`,'MO' AS Type,scr_adress AS Msisdn,TEXT as text,CHAR_LENGTH(TEXT) AS QtyOfSymbols,'OK' AS `Status` FROM archiveoutgoingsms
                  WHERE 1=1 AND send_date BETWEEN '2015-06-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-14 23:59:59') ORDER BY `Date` ASC LIMIT 0 ,100
```

What is when use

```
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

insted

```
ORDER BY `Date` ASC
```

?

Comment: No this is not same ! It will be same if there is single table but i have to query with two table. So sometime ID will be same and time will be different !

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Here is the result of this Query Explain !

Image can view by open in new tab ! it's too small here !

Answer (score 0):

Somehow mysql don't use index recieved_datetime in first part of UNION

You can tell MYSQL force use of index

Query 1:

```
EXPLAIN (SELECT id AS ID,`recieved_datetime` `Date`,'MT' AS Type,src_adress AS Msisdn,TEXT as text,CHAR_LENGTH(TEXT) AS QtyOfSymbols,'OK' AS `Status` FROM archiveincomingsms FORCE INDEX(recieved_datetime)
              WHERE 1=1 AND recieved_datetime BETWEEN '2015-06-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-14 23:59:59')
              UNION ALL
              (SELECT id AS ID,`send_date` `Date`,'MO' AS Type,scr_adress AS Msisdn,TEXT as text,CHAR_LENGTH(TEXT) AS QtyOfSymbols,'OK' AS `Status` FROM archiveoutgoingsms
              WHERE 1=1 AND send_date BETWEEN '2015-06-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-14 23:59:59') ORDER BY `Date` ASC LIMIT 0 ,100
```

Query 2:

```
(SELECT id AS ID,`recieved_datetime` `Date`,'MT' AS Type,src_adress AS Msisdn,TEXT as text,CHAR_LENGTH(TEXT) AS QtyOfSymbols,'OK' AS `Status` FROM archiveincomingsms FORCE INDEX(recieved_datetime)
              WHERE 1=1 AND recieved_datetime BETWEEN '2015-06-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-14 23:59:59')
              UNION ALL
              (SELECT id AS ID,`send_date` `Date`,'MO' AS Type,scr_adress AS Msisdn,TEXT as text,CHAR_LENGTH(TEXT) AS QtyOfSymbols,'OK' AS `Status` FROM archiveoutgoingsms
              WHERE 1=1 AND send_date BETWEEN '2015-06-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-14 23:59:59') ORDER BY `Date` ASC LIMIT 0 ,100
```

What about to use timestamp instead datetime 2015-06-14 00:00:00

Comment: Instead AND recieved_datetime BETWEEN '2015-06-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-14 23:59:59') you may find for this conditions in another queries and use id for between

Comment: What about to use timestamp instead datetime 2015-06-14 00:00:00

Comment: I don't think timestamp make different in this query ! I have already tried a lot ! :( Tired while trying :(

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE archiveincomingsms;` -- it is clearer and more readable that what you provided.  Plus it shows the Engine and Index(es).

For the `UNION`, you need

```
INDEX(send_date),
INDEX(received_date)
```

However, since you are looking at a month's worth of data, that could be a significant chunk of the table.  If it is more than something like 20% of the table, it will do a table scan (or two scans), meaning that the UNION does not help.

A side note:  Instead of

```
          AND  send_date BETWEEN '2015-06-14 00:00:00'
                             AND '2015-07-14 23:59:59'
```

This would be cleaner and easier:

```
          AND  send_date >= '2015-06-14'
          AND  send_date <  '2015-06-14' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

and it automatically handles short months and year boundaries.

The tablenames are hard to distinguish; they all look like

```
archivemiscellanyms
```

Oh, I am not finished (now that I stare at the table names to see that they are different)...

Add `ORDER BY...LIMIT` to each part of the `UNION`:

```
( SELECT ... ORDER BY received_datetime LIMIT    100 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... ORDER BY send_date         LIMIT    100 )
ORDER BY date                           LIMIT 0, 100
```

If you are going to "paginate" (cringe), then do this for, say, the 3rd page:

```
( SELECT ... ORDER BY received_datetime LIMIT      300 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... ORDER BY send_date         LIMIT      300 )
ORDER BY date                           LIMIT 200, 100
```

*Now* the indexes will be usable.  However, as the user goes from page to page, it will get slower and slower.

You could *probably* speed up the subsequent pages by "remembering where you left off".  See [my pagination blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination);